In Powershell and PSWriteHTML : Click Table Row and Show only the One Chart
Hello and sorry for my English.
I Have this Code that shows 3 objects in a table and each object in a chart line.
$DT_P_i = 0
$DataTable = @()   
for(($l_i=0); ($l_i -lt 10); ($l_i++))
{
   $DataTable += @(
      [PSCustomObject] @{
         Names = "My Name " + $l_i.ToString()
         Procc = @()
      }
   )

   for (($l_j = 0); ($l_j -lt 2); ($l_j++))
   {
      $DT_P_I++
      
      $DataTable[$l_i].Procc += @(
         [PSCustomObject]@{
            PNames = "Procc " + $DT_P_I.ToString()
            Times = @()
            Values = @()
         }
      )

      for (($l_v = 0); ($l_v -lt 3); ($l_v++))
      {
         $DataTable[$l_i].Procc[$l_j].Times += $l_v.ToString()
         $DataTable[$l_i].Procc[$l_j].Values += $l_v.ToString()
      }
   }
}

$DT_Unique = $DataTable.Names | Get-Unique -AsString
   
$Table_N_PN = @()

foreach ($DT in $DataTable)
{
   foreach ($DTP in $DT.Procc)
   {
      $Table_N_PN += @(
         [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name=$DT.Names
            PName =$DTP.PNames
         }
      )
   }
}


$TableProcesses = "TableProcesses"

New-HTML -TitleText 'Names - Processes - Charts' -Online -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\Test.html {
   New-HTMLSection -HeaderText "TABLE: Names and Processes" -HeaderTextSize 25{
      New-HTMLTable -DataTable $DT_Unique -PreContent{"<h1>Names</h1>"}{
         New-TableEvent -TableID $TableProcesses -SourceColumnID 0 -TargetColumnID 0
      }
      New-HTMLTable -DataTable $Table_N_PN -DataTableID $TableProcesses -PreContent{"<h1>Processes</h1>"}
   }

   New-HTMLSection -HeaderText "Charts" -HeaderTextSize 25{
      New-HTMLPanel{ 

         $BGcolors = [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]) 
         [bool]$l_show_yellow = $false

         foreach ($Object in $DataTable) {

            if ($l_show_yellow -eq $true) {$l_show_yellow = $false; $Color = $BGcolors[1]; } else {$l_show_yellow = $true; $Color = $BGcolors[14]; }
            $str = "Chart for : " + $Object.Names
            New-HTMLSection -HeaderText $str -HeaderTextSize 20  -BackgroundColor $Color{ 
               New-HTMLPanel{   
                  foreach ($Pr in $Object.Procc) {
                     $str = $Pr.PNames
                     New-HTMLSection -HeaderText $str  -HeaderTextSize 14{ 
                        New-HTMLPanel -BackgroundColor White{   
                           New-HTMLChart {
                              New-ChartAxisX -Names $Pr.Times
                              New-ChartLine -Name $Pr.PNames -Value $Pr.Values
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
} -ShowHTML


I want to click to one row of the table (f.e. My Object 1) and show only the Chart for Object 1
Can you help me please ?
Thank you all
Try to click on a row table and show the chart for this object

This code shows in Top Section all the Objects that I have and in Bottom Section All values from All Objects in Charts. I have 30 Objects on my script and I see All Charts from All Objects.
That I want is to click to an object on the table and see only the chart from that object. For Example: If I click on the first row that has the "My Object 1" I want to see only the Chart that is for "My Object 1" and not the others.
I don't know how to Show Only the Selected Object Chart, or Hide the others when I click the row with the object in the table.

I change the code... as I have it now

Could you edit the question to elaborate on what the current behaviour of the code above is? Are you asking after how to get a method to handle clicks on table rows? Are you asking about ways to hide or to show the charts?

It looks like you're using the PSWriteHTML module. Please add the information as to what module you're using to the question.

I Have install only PSWriteHTML

I change the code as I have it now... If you try to reproduce it, you will see that when you click in a row on the Left table(Names), in the Right table(Processes) shows only the processes that has the selected Name. That I want is to Show In Charts only the chart for the selected Name.

I found the way: How to do it... I write the code if anyone want to use it...
    $DT_P_i = 0
    $DataTable = @()   
    for(($l_i=0); ($l_i -lt 10); ($l_i++))
    {
       $DataTable += @(
          [PSCustomObject] @{
             Names = "My Name " + $l_i.ToString()
             Procc = @()
          }
       )
    
       for (($l_j = 0); ($l_j -lt 2); ($l_j++))
       {
          $DT_P_I++
          
          $DataTable[$l_i].Procc += @(
             [PSCustomObject]@{
                PNames = "Procc " + $DT_P_I.ToString()
                Times = @()
                Values = @()
             }
          )
    
          for (($l_v = 0); ($l_v -lt 3); ($l_v++))
          {
             $DataTable[$l_i].Procc[$l_j].Times += $l_v.ToString()
             $DataTable[$l_i].Procc[$l_j].Values += $l_v.ToString()
          }
       }
    }
    
    $DT_Unique = $DataTable.Names | Get-Unique -AsString
       
    $Table_N_PN = @()
    
    foreach ($DT in $DataTable)
    {
       foreach ($DTP in $DT.Procc)
       {
          $Table_N_PN += @(
             [PSCustomObject]@{
                Name=$DT.Names
                PName =$DTP.PNames
             }
          )
       }
    }
    
    
    $TableProcesses = "TableProcesses"
    
    New-HTML -TitleText 'Names - Processes - Charts' -Online -FilePath $PSScriptRoot\Test.html {
       New-HTMLSection -HeaderText "TABLE: Names and Processes" -HeaderTextSize 25{
          New-HTMLTable -DataTable $DT_Unique -PreContent{"<h1>Names</h1>"} -DataTableID "NamesTable"{
             New-TableEvent -TableID $TableProcesses -SourceColumnID 0 -TargetColumnID 0
          }
    
          New-HTMLTable -DataTable $Table_N_PN -DataTableID $TableProcesses -PreContent{"<h1>Processes</h1>"}
       }
    
       New-HTMLSection -HeaderText "Charts" -HeaderTextSize 25{
          New-HTMLPanel{ 
    
             $BGcolors = [enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]) 
             [bool]$l_show_yellow = $false
             foreach ($Object in $DataTable) {
    
                if ($l_show_yellow -eq $true) {$l_show_yellow = $false; $Color = $BGcolors[1]; } else {$l_show_yellow = $true; $Color = $BGcolors[14]; }
                $str = "Chart for : " + $Object.Names
    
                # Manually adding data-name
                "<div data-name='$($Object.Names)'>"
    
                # Use panels for each chart
                New-HTMLSection -HeaderText $str -HeaderTextSize 20 -BackgroundColor $Color {
                   New-HTMLPanel {
                      
                      foreach ($Pr in $Object.Procc) {
                         $str = $Pr.PNames
                         New-HTMLSection -HeaderText $str -HeaderTextSize 14 {
                            New-HTMLPanel -BackgroundColor White {
                               New-HTMLChart {
                                  New-ChartAxisX -Names $Pr.Times
                                  New-ChartLine -Name $Pr.PNames -Value $Pr.Values
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      }
                      
                   }
                }
                "</div>"  # Closing the div
             }
          }
       }
       # Adding JavaScript with New-HTMLPanel
       New-HTMLPanel {
          "<script>
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
              var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table tr');
              rows.forEach(function(row) {
                  row.addEventListener('click', function() {
                      var selectedName = this.cells[0].textContent.trim(); // Get the first column
    
                      // Selecting the chart based on data-name
                      var chartToShow = document.querySelector('div[data-name=`"' + selectedName + '`"]');
    
                      if (chartToShow) {
                          var allCharts = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-name]');
                          allCharts.forEach(function(chart) {
                              chart.style.display = 'none'; // Hiding all charts
                          });
                          chartToShow.style.display = 'block'; // Displaying only the selected chart
                      } else {
                          console.error('Chart not found: ' + selectedName);
                      }
                  });
              });
          });
          </script>"
      }
    } -ShowHTML

